# AWS XRay - Failed to begin subsegment named 'AWSSecurityTokenService': segment cannot be found, during a request

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-xray

I am trying to set up AWS XRay in a new(ish) Spring Boot application.

I would like to test it locally before putting it into production.  Locally this application runs with a dynamoDB client and STS to assume the role to call dynamo.

The service starts up fine, loads all the beans, but when I make a call to the service it fails with

```
Failed to begin subsegment named 'AWSSecurityTokenService': segment cannot be found
```

When it is trying to call dynamoDB to save an item.  I thought that if you added the aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdy dependencies that packages like AWSSecurityTokenService would automatically get the context subsegment during a request?  What am I missing?

I have added the following to the pom.xml:

```
    <!-- AWS XRay -->
      <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2-instrumentor</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the following Aspect:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRay;
import com.amazonaws.xray.entities.Subsegment;

@Aspect
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class XRayInspector {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XRayInspector.class);

    @Around("!execution(* com.things.service.config..*(..)) && " +
            "execution(* com.things.service.controller..*(..)) && " +
            "execution(* com.things.service.factory..*(..)) && " +
            "execution(* com.things.service.exceptions..*(..)) && " +
            "execution(* com.things.service.security..*(..)) && " +
            "execution(* com.things.service.model..*(..)) && " +
            "execution(* com.things.service.service..*(..))")
    public Object logExecutionTime(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return this.processXRayTrace(joinPoint);
    }

    protected Object processXRayTrace(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        try {
            final Subsegment subsegment = AWSXRay.beginSubsegment(pjp.getSignature().getName());
            subsegment.setMetadata(generateMetadata(pjp, subsegment));
            return conditionalProceed(pjp);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            AWSXRay.getCurrentSegment().addException(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            LOG.trace("Ending Subsegment");
            AWSXRay.endSubsegment();
        }
    }

    public static Object conditionalProceed(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        if (pjp.getArgs().length == 0) {
            return pjp.proceed();
        } else {
            return pjp.proceed(pjp.getArgs());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<String, Object>> generateMetadata(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, final Subsegment subsegment) {
        final Map<String, Map<String, Object>> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        final Map<String, Object> classInfo = new HashMap<>();
        classInfo.put("Class", pjp.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
        metadata.put("ClassInfo", classInfo);
        return metadata;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any initialization code? If the STS call is made before a request actually comes into the your X-Ray enabled service (or out of band of the request), this will cause a missing context exception. We advise either to omit any calls that arn't apart of the request path (using an untraced AWS client) or set the AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING env variable to LOG_ERROR:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-configuration.html#xray-sdk-java-configuration-envvars